# Theorem about flat module and ideal over a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $I$ be a right ideal of $R$ (a commutative ring) then $M$ is flat if and only if 
    $$0\to I\otimes_R M\to R \otimes_R M \cong M$$ is exact.

($\Rightarrow$) If $M$ is flat and $i:I \to R$ is canonical injection, then we have $I\otimes_R M\xrightarrow{i\otimes 1} R\otimes_R M$ is an injection and following $R \otimes_R M \cong M$, we have the proof.

How can I proof ($\Leftarrow$), thankyou so much.

Comment: I want to tell you to check any textbook on homological algebra. E.g., Rotman. That said, why are you trying to prove this? What is your motivation?

Comment: Also in order for $M$ to be flat, this needs to hold for every right ideal $I$.

Comment: Here's the [stacks project's proof.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HD)

Comment: Thankyou so much :D